# Remove woocommerce sidebar on shop/front page only

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm building a site based on TwentyTwelve (child theme) and I'm using woocommerce.
On my shop page (is also the sites frontpage) I want to remove the sidebar.

I came up with this code:

```
if(is_front_page() ){
remove_action( 'woocommerce_before_main_content', 'woocommerce_output_content_wrapper', 10);
remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_main_content', 'woocommerce_output_content_wrapper_end', 10);
remove_action( 'woocommerce_sidebar', 'woocommerce_get_sidebar', 10 );

add_action('woocommerce_before_main_content', 'twentytwelve_child_wrapper_start', 10);
add_action('woocommerce_after_main_content', 'twentytwelve_child_wrapper_end', 10);

function twentytwelve_child_wrapper_start() {
   echo '<div id="shop">';
}

function twentytwelve_child_wrapper_end() {
  echo '</div>';
}
}
```

It works but it removes the sidebar on ALL woo pages (except the cart and checkout page)
and it should be on the shop / frontpage (and searchresults for that matter)

Bottom line: I can't get my conditional statement right. Please help.
Because I'm a bit of a newbie, keep it simple please. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you use css rather than php? if you target the body class of the front page like this:

```
body.frontpage .sidebar{
   display:none;
}
```

Comment: you'll need to replace the frontpage & sidebar classes with relevant ones.

Comment: thank you for your reply. Unless I'm doing something wrong will this solution not work. WP/Woo injects the same id's and divs for the storefront as for the single products page. If I'm doing something wrong... please advice.

Comment: Do you have a link to your site at all? Wordpress usually adds a class to the body of the homepage called "home"

Comment: Sorry Alex, my site is still local but I will investigate the home class. I let you know. Thanks!

Comment: Great, it works like a charm. I had to set the content area "Primary" to a width of 100% after changing the display options and now it is ok. I will accept your answer. Thanks a bunch!

Comment: Hmmm, something came up. When I do a product search the sidebar on the result page returns. I tried the same trick but it is not working. The home class is replaced by the archive tag and no way I can trick it into the same result as with the homepage. May I ask... do you have a suggestion? Thanks in advance

Comment: Would you be able to copy the source code of the body tag on the result page please?

Comment: Here it is: <body class="archive search search-results post-type-archive post-type-archive-product logged-in admin-bar custom-background woocommerce woocommerce-page custom-font-enabled single-author customize-support"> Can you make a good tasting cocktail out of it? I no I can't..... ;)

Comment: If you don't wish to have the sidebar on the search results page all you need to do is copy this - `body.search-results .sidebar` replace sidebar with your sidebar class and paste it after the same rule for hiding it on the homepage so you will end up with something like this: `body.home .sidebar, body.search-results .sidebar {display:none;}`

Comment: OK, thank you. Just a question. Does it affect only the Woocommerce search results? That's what I aiming for. The normal site search has to remain intact.

Comment: This will affect all search results pages, if you want to narrow it down to just Woocommerce results you can do the following `body.home .sidebar, body.search-results.woocommerce-page .sidebar {display:none;}` hopefully that should only target pages that are using woocommerce.

Comment: It's really super. Thank you for sharing your knowledge.